# How to play multiple sounds in ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad

I am developing a game for iPad using java script.

I have to play 4 sounds in which one is background sound and others will play based on some events.

As iPad doesn't allow us to play multiple sound simultaneously,I am playing continuously background sound when any event occurs I am stopping background sound and playing other sound after completion of this sound resuming background sound.

But while loading sound is taking so much time, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a buffer of an HTML5 sound. I mean, you create and load the src files at the start, and then you play them and reuse them.